# Reversing a linked list with a recursive algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, list, recursion, iteration

online and on books I found some algorithms about reversing a list with an iterative method, like this I thnk that is the common used algorithm

```
link listReverse(link x) {
    link t, y = x, r = NULL;
    while (y != NULL) {
        t = y->next;
        y->next = r;
        r = y;
        y = t;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Note: the node is implemented in this way:

```
typedef sturct node *link:
struct node {
    item Item;
    link next;
};
```

I have got some problems in comprending how this algorithm works and I made this one:

```
link init() {
    link x;

    x = malloc(sizeof *x);

    x->next = NULL;

    return x;
}

link listReverse(link start) {
    link newNode = init();

    listReverseR(start, newNode, 1);

    return newNode;
}

link listReverseR(link start, link n, double start_d) {

    if (start == NULL)
        return n;

    n = listReverseR(start->next, n, 0);
    n->next = (start_d) ? NULL : start;
    return n->next;
}
```

Is it good? And is it equal in complexity? The iterative one is O(n), I think that this is O(n) too.

P.S. The recursive code is based on a list with a dummy head so init() function initialize this dummy node as start of a new list.

Comment: Looks like you are asking for a code review.

Comment: A recursive algorithm is rarely the best approach in C. Compilers can "resolve" the recursion sometimes, a plain *tail-recursion* will be compiled to iterative code by a good optimizing compiler. But if this isn't possible, recursion uses a lot of stack (with the risk of overflowing it) and the function calls cost some runtime as well.

Comment: On of the main concerns with the recursive solution is it's O(n) space, and it's "stack" based space - which is usually a scarce resource (compared to dynamic allocation space, for example). The iterative solution is O(1) extra space, so it does not have this issue (and the input itself is allocated on heap most likely)

Comment: `listReverse` returns a pointer that you don't use. Does this work?! No!?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yeah it works.. it returns a new head containing the reversed list. newNode is used in the recursive function and it is initialized, so it isn't a not utilized pointer. There is only a bit of memory leak because I didn't put a free(start); in listReverse to free old head. I remember that the head in this case is a dummy node.